# how to fix GCM 1000 message limit,want to send message to a database of 10000?

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays

i am using the following code to send GCM messages using PHP and MySQL. Please help me out so that it can send GCM messages in lots of 1000 to a database of 10,000 registered users.

Before crossing 1000 users, this script worked fine; but after 1000 users, no one receives push
the error received by this script is "**Number of messages on bulk (1082) exceeds maximum allowed (1000)** "

```
//GCM Send Notification
function px_sendGCM($message, $type, $regid) {
global $wpdb;
$px_table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'gcm_users';
$options = get_option('gcm_setting');
$apiKey = $options['api-key'];
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$result;
$id;

if($regid == 010) {
$id = px_getIds();
}else {
$id = $regid;
}

if($id == 010 && $id >= 1000){
$newId = array_chunk($id, 1000);
foreach ($newId as $inner_id) {
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $inner_id,
        'data' => array($type => $message) 
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization' => 'key=' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    );

    $result = wp_remote_post($url, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => $headers,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'sslverify' => false,
        'body' => json_encode($fields) )
    );
}
}else {
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $id,
    'data' => array($type => $message)
);

$headers = array(
    'Authorization' => 'key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
);

$result = wp_remote_post($url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'headers' => $headers,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'sslverify' => false,
    'body' => json_encode($fields))
    );

   }

$msg = $result['body'];
$answer = json_decode($msg);
$cano = px_canonical($answer);
$suc = $answer->{'success'};
$fail = $answer->{'failure'};
$options = get_option('gcm_setting');
if($options['debug'] != false){
$inf= "<div id='message' class='updated'><p><b>".__('Message    sent.','px_gcm')."</b><i>&nbsp;&nbsp;($message)</i></p><p>$msg</p></div>";
}else {
$inf= "<div id='message' class='updated'><p><b>".__('Message    sent.','px_gcm')."</b><i>&nbsp;&nbsp;($message)</i></p><p>".__('success:','px_gcm')." $suc  &nbsp;&nbsp;".__('fail:','px_gcm')." $fail </p></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GCM allows you to send 1000 messages in a single request. So if you want to send messages to more than 1000 customers, use loop which will call your function px_sendGCM($message, $type, $regid) for every 1000 customers

your code should be:

```
//GCM Send Notification
function px_sendGCM($message, $type, $regid) {
global $wpdb;
$px_table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'gcm_users';
$options = get_option('gcm_setting');
$apiKey = $options['api-key'];
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$result;
$id;

if(sizeof($regid) == 010) {
$id = px_getIds(); //Can you post this function, what is this condition for?
}else {
$id = $regid;
}

if(sizeof($id) > 1000){
$newId = array_chunk($id, 1000);
foreach ($newId as $inner_id) {
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $inner_id,
        'data' => array($type => $message) 
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization' => 'key=' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    );

    $result = wp_remote_post($url, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => $headers,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'sslverify' => false,
        'body' => json_encode($fields) )
    );
}
}else {
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $id,
    'data' => array($type => $message)
);

$headers = array(
    'Authorization' => 'key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
);

$result = wp_remote_post($url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'headers' => $headers,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'sslverify' => false,
    'body' => json_encode($fields))
    );

   }

$msg = $result['body'];
$answer = json_decode($msg);
$cano = px_canonical($answer);
$suc = $answer->{'success'};
$fail = $answer->{'failure'};
$options = get_option('gcm_setting');
if($options['debug'] != false){
$inf= "<div id='message' class='updated'><p><b>".__('Message    sent.','px_gcm')."</b><i>&nbsp;&nbsp;($message)</i></p><p>$msg</p></div>";
}else {
$inf= "<div id='message' class='updated'><p><b>".__('Message    sent.','px_gcm')."</b><i>&nbsp;&nbsp;($message)</i></p><p>".__('success:','px_gcm')." $suc  &nbsp;&nbsp;".__('fail:','px_gcm')." $fail </p></div>";
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that in above mentioned code

Comment: you have a loop in your code but your condition 
if($id == 010 && $id >= 1000) is wrong. so your if part containing loop isn't executed and always your else part is executed which is causing this error

Comment: sir im not getting any idea how to fix it,,, can your please correct this loop condition  if($id == 010 && $id >= 1000)

Comment: function px_getIds() {
    global $wpdb;
    $px_table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'gcm_users';
    $devices = array();
    $sql = "SELECT gcm_regid FROM $px_table_name";
    $res = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    if ($res != false) {
        foreach($res as $row){
            array_push($devices, $row->gcm_regid);
        }
    }
 
    return $devices;
}

Comment: See the full code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_VDsMSwf1ZBcHN0dDJ5a09mLUU/view?usp=sharing: